# How to convert XML into CIF format?

Tags: xml

I am completely new to the CIF Arriba format and I was wondering if someone can help convert this XML into a CIF format?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Index SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.012/cXML.dtd">
<Index loadmode="Full">
 <SupplierID domain="NetworkID"></SupplierID>
 <Comments xml:lang="en-US"></Comments>
 <IndexItem>
  <IndexItemPunchout>
   <ItemID>
    <SupplierPartID></SupplierPartID>
   </ItemID>
   <PunchoutDetail>
    <Description</Description>
    <URL></URL>
    <Classification</Classification>
    <Extrinsic></Extrinsic>
   </PunchoutDetail>
  </IndexItemPunchout>
 </IndexItem>
</Index>
```